# How to remove a line if it contains a private use area character?

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, text-files

Given a file with characters in private use area, like this:

```
$ cat textfile.txt | less
10 翴 30 <U+E4D1>       ten-thirty in ... three ... two ... one .
- 10 翴 45だи<U+E145>砆 秂 <U+E18E>     it 's a slam-dunk .
<U+E707> 10 翴 <U+E6C4>ㄓ ?     so you will be home by 10:00 ?
10 翴 牧 よ<U+E6BC>ㄓ<U+E5EC>   bogey at 10 o'clock .
- 10 翴 牧 よ<U+E6BC>い盠       - ten o'clock , lieutenant , 10 o'clock !
10 翴 牧 よ<U+E6BC>绰玭 i see it , 8 o'clock , heading south !
10 翴 筁<U+E5EC>        it 's past 10:00 .
<U+E80B>ぱ 10 翴 非<U+E1A0>筁ㄓ be here tomorrow , 10:00 sharp .
- 10 ， 老搭档 有 人 开枪 ， 疑犯 拒捕  shots firing . suspect 's fleeing .
- 1 -0 而已     - only 1-0 .
- 1 -0 而已     - only 1-0 .
```

**How can I remove a line if there're any character having beyond the  unicode byte point?**

I've tried this:

```
# ord(u'\uE000') == 57344
for line in open('test.txt'):
    if any(ord(i) >57344 for i in line):
        pass
    else:
        print (line)
```

But I can't seem to get rid of the lines that contains the PUA characters.

**How can I achieve the same in the unix bash with sed/awk or something instead of using Python?**

**Note that I still want to keep lines that are valid unicode and not just keep lines with the ascii characters**. E.g. I want to keep the last 3rd line with the chinese characters and "... shots firing . suspect 's fleeing ." (for some reason i can't type the chinese part in the question because SO is showing error with the chinese characters.)

Comment: Note that i'm not trying to remove non-english characters. I am trying to remove the full line if any of the characters fall into the PUA. I still want to keep lines like `- 10 ， 老搭档 有 人 开枪 ， 疑犯 拒捕  shots firing . suspect 's fleeing .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your criteria (`ord(i) > 57344`) for checking if a character belongs to a [private use area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) is incorrect:

> Currently, three private use areas are defined: one in the Basic Multilingual Plane (`U+E000–U+F8FF`), and one each in, and nearly covering, planes 15 and 16 (`U+F0000–U+FFFFD`, `U+100000–U+10FFFD`)

Here is the fixed Python 3 code:

```
pua_ranges = ( (0xE000, 0xF8FF), (0xF0000, 0xFFFFD), (0x100000, 0x10FFFD) )

def is_pua_codepoint(c):
    return any(a <= c <= b for (a,b) in pua_ranges)

for line in open('test.txt', 'r'):
    if any(is_pua_codepoint(ord(i)) for i in line):
        pass
    else:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

This grep command will match any line that does not contain a PUA character in the U+E000–U+F8FF range:

```
grep -Pv "[\xe0\x00-\xf8\xff]"
```

Comment: This specifically requires GNU `grep`, though.  Mac used to have `grep -P` but it was removed.

Comment: I am using GNU grep 2.25, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: You might also need to use a different locale but I'm not sure.  Maybe try with `LC_ALL=POSIX` and/or `LC_ALL=C`?

Comment: @tripleee No success

Comment: Tried it on this file https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alvations/5bf8e28dba700a66fb47689a29ab2823/raw/1a9606fcd932f74c09f9eff81e116a3a7c3d97b4/test.txt and the regex didn't work. It threw every line, including the last 3.